# How to dynamically change target for unit tests in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have a project that has multiple different targets/schemes (~38 of them as of writing this question) and I am trying to get unit testing working properly across all of the different targets. I got things working with one target, and tried adding my testing target to all of the different schemes, but it looks like when tests run for each scheme they actually run on the same, original target.

Looking in the project file I see that there's a specific Host Application associated with my testing target, and in the build settings the Bundle Loader and Test Host point to that same Host Application.

Is there any way to override those values for each scheme to run the tests against the current scheme's build target? Or some other way to set up a single test target to run across multiple build targets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run the tests from the command line, or from an CI tool, like Jenkins, you can instruct [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) to use the build settings that you provide. A simple usage example would be:

```
xcodebuild -scheme SomeScheme test TEST_HOST=target
```

You can control almost (if not any) build setting from Xcode, like code coverage generation, build directory, derived data directory, code sign identity, etc.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can select the scheme when you run tests with Xcode server.

Look at WWDC 2014 continues integration talk for a walk through on how to set it up

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-415/

It's using Xcode 6 but it's very similar process to Xcode 7

Also check this CI(continues integration) guideline from apple 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/adopt_continuous_integration.html

Comment: It would be super-nice if you wrote the relevant video time moment. :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering how to do that with UI tests (maybe it is working with unit tests, too), this is what I came up with:

1. First, we need to build the application which we are going to use to host our UI tests:

`xcodebuild -scheme "<appSchemeName>" build -destination "<yourDestination>"`

More info about destination parameter: https://mokacoding.com/blog/xcodebuild-destination-options/

2. Then, we need to run tests on our newly built application:

`xcodebuild -scheme "<uiTestsSchemeName>" -destination "<yourDestination>" test TEST_TARGET_NAME="<yourNewlyBuiltAppTargetName>"`

Destinations should match, since after the build `.app` is generated in your DerivedData folder, which will be used for UI tests hosting application